# (Q&A) How to combine two similar list or string into one?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two similar strings `"arcda"` and `"fcdb6"`, or two lists `{a, c, b, e, f, h}` and `{a, d, c, g, b, e, h, i}`. How to combine them into one while keeping the order "as much as possible"? The strings should merge to `"arfcdba6"` and the list to `{a, d, c, g, b, e, f, h, i}`.

Comment: @yode I rephrased a bit, feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: @Kuba No (hence the `"`). For example, I don't understand why `"arfcdba6"` is better than `"arfcdab6"`.

Comment: [wikipedia: Shortest Common Supersequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem)?

Answer (score 9):

I will introduce a undocumented function `` Experimental`ShortestSupersequence `` to implement this

```
Experimental`ShortestSupersequence["arcda", "fcdb6"]
```

> "arfcdba6"

```
Experimental`ShortestSupersequence[{a,c,b,e,f,h},{a,d,c,g,b,e,h,i}]
```

> {a,d,c,g,b,e,f,h,i}

And it have a option `IgnoreCase` to process string.

Comment: How do you know this? Out of curiosity.

Comment: @user6014 It is just from a accidental glance in ``Names["Experimental`*"]``. :)

Comment: neat! thanks for sharing.